# How are you/ how were you?

Tags: tense

What is the difference between How are you and How were you.
Which is more appropriate to use?

Comment: They are in different tenses.

Comment: In which context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How *were* you?" is past tense. It implies that you are inquiring about how a person was at a previous point in time. One case I can think of where it would be used is when you were not able to attend someone's recital, etc. You would say "How did you do?" or "How were you?"

"How *are* you?" is present tense. It means that you are inquiring about how a person is at the current time. This is something that you typically hear people say to someone, after greeting them.

Comment: I think it maybe not the tense. I heard someone pronounced "how are you" just like "how were you."